# xcopy fails in AppVeyor, works at home: Invalid number of parameters

Tags: windows, command-line, xcopy, appveyor

The command
`xcopy "$SITEPACKAGES\\google" "build\\lib\\google" /i /e /h` fails with `Invalid number of parameters`  on Windows on AppVeyor (Visual Studio 2019).

I’ve confirmed the correct syntax of the command in my Windows virtual machine on my computer where the command works as expected, and I’ve confirmed the correct setting of the `$SITEPACKAGES` variable and the escaped backslashes by echoing the same line: `echo "$SITEPACKAGES\\google" "build\\lib\\google" /i /e /h` produces `C:\Python37-x64\Lib\site-packages\google build\lib\google /i /e /h`, now with the quotes not showing anymore as expected.

The command is run from a shell schript as a normal command from `appveyor.yml` like so:

```
build_script:
    - cmd: "sh wxPython/build/Windows/build-all.sh"
```

I’ve also tried not to escape the backslashes, but with same result.

I'm lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some backslashes missing, as you can see from my attempts:

```
C:\Users\Gebruiker>xcopy C:\Python37-x64\Lib\site-packages\google build\lib\google /i /e /h
File not found - google
0 File(s) copied

C:\Users\Gebruiker>xcopy C:\Python37-x64\Lib\site-packages\google\ build\lib\google\ /i /e /h
Invalid path
0 File(s) copied
```

Anyway, I'd advise to make sure you always have double quotes around your paths, you never know when a space might arrive in a directory's name.

Comment: This did not lead to a functioning result, and the output in your own test supports this with "Invalid path". Anyways, the command at the top of my original post works on my virtual machine and is therefore known to be correct. It doesn't work on AppVeyor.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure yet what the problem is, but it has shown in another instance that there’s some real problem here. My [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64433096/signtool-options-interpreted-as-files-on-appveyor) shows a similar behaviour. It seems that options are being interpreted as file name input.

Meanwhile I've wanted to post a workaround that helped me, which is to copy through Python:

`python -c "import shutil; shutil.copytree('$SITEPACKAGES\\google', 'build\\lib\\google')"`

Comment: Is it possible that something is messing up your double quotes into locale dependent ones? (I mean `“` and `”`, which are different than `"`).

Answer (score 0):

Found the cleanest solution: Don't mix Windows and Linux (WSL) environments in AppVeyor (or probably generally).

Either call a shell script using `sh` or `bash` and then copy folders the Unix way with `cp -r $SITEPACKAGES/google build/lib/` with `appveyor.yml`:

```
  build_script: 
    - cmd: sh somecommand.sh
```

or do it the Windows way and call a Windows batch script directly and then use Windows’ copy commands `xcopy "$SITEPACKAGES\\google" "build\\lib\\google" /i /e /h` with `appveyor.yml`:

```
  build_script: 
    - somecommand.bat
```