# signtool: options interpreted as files on AppVeyor

Tags: cmd, appveyor, signtool

I’m having this super weird behaviour on an AppVeyor build (Visual Studio 2019): In a shell script (cmd.exe), when signing my app with `signtool`, all the options are interpreted as files (`signtool` can sign multiple files at once).

The line `"$WINDOWSKITBIN\\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd SHA256 /n "Jan Gerner" /v /debug "build\\TypeWorld.exe"`  produces:

```
Successfully signed: build\TypeWorld.exe
Number of files successfully Signed: 1
Number of errors: 10
SignTool Error: File not found: C:/Program Files/Git/tr
SignTool Error: File not found: http://timestamp.digicert.com
SignTool Error: File not found: C:/Program Files/Git/td
SignTool Error: File not found: sha256
SignTool Error: File not found: C:/Program Files/Git/fd
SignTool Error: File not found: SHA256
SignTool Error: File not found: N:/
SignTool Error: File not found: Jan Gerner
SignTool Error: File not found: V:/
SignTool Error: File not found: C:/Program Files/Git/debug
```

The wanted file `TypeWorld.exe` is signed, just without all the options, and all the options are interpreted as files to sign which then aren’t found, obviously.

I've confirmed the escaped backslashes and folder variable to be correct.

This line `echo "$WINDOWSKITBIN\\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd SHA256 /n "Jan Gerner" /v /debug "build\\TypeWorld.exe"`

produces the expected rendering: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd SHA256 /n Jan Gerner /v /debug build\TypeWorld.exe`

I tried running the same in PowerShell, to same result.

Comment: Could you please email complete `appveyor.yml` (with sensitive data redacted/removed) to support@appveyor.com.

Comment: I emailed it. Very grateful for a timely response 

Comment: Ah, I see, the message trapped into junk folder on Monday! Looking into it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of what the AppVeyor staff recommended (also by email) helped.

What did help in the end is to not mix Windows and Linux (WSL) environments. In `appveyor.yml` I was calling the build script through `sh` (or later `bash` at the recommendation of AppVeyor staff):

```
build_script: 
    - cmd: C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe wxPython/build/Windows/build-all.sh
```

Instead, for some commands it's better to keep things simple, so I converted the code signing part to a good old Windows batch file:

```
build_script: 
    - wxPython/build/Windows/build-sign.bat
```

Inside the batch file, the line
`signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd SHA256 /n "Jan Gerner" /v "build\\TypeWorld.exe"` executes fine.